# Problema para mostrar mi imagen en Angular

Tags: java, html, angular, spring-boot

Estaba haciendo un proyecto donde tenia que crear un paciente con su respectiva imagen, el problema surge cuando tengo que mostrar el paciente.El paciente se me guardo bien en la base de datos y la imagen se encuentra en la respectivo directorio de almacenamiento.

**Mi logica de guardado de imagen en el backend:**

```
  if(!file.isEmpty()){
        //Path directorioImagen = Paths.get("C:/Users/Lautaro/Desktop/Proyectos/proyecto-clinica-odontologica/frontend/src/imagenes");
        String rutaAbsoluta = "C://Users//Lautaro//Desktop//Proyectos//proyecto-clinica-odontologica//imagenes";

        try {
            byte[] byteImg = file.getBytes();
           Path rutaCompleta = Paths.get(rutaAbsoluta + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(rutaCompleta,byteImg);
            paciente.setImg(file.getOriginalFilename());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Imagen Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class ImgConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);

        registry.addResourceHandler("/imagenes/**").addResourceLocations("file:/C:/Users/Lautaro/Desktop/Proyectos/proyecto-clinica-odontologica/imagenes/");
    }
}
```

**Despues en mi HTML tengo lo siguiente :**

```
<div class="perfil-container">
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/imagenes/{{ persona.img }}" alt="Foto de perfil">
    <div class="informacion-personal">
      <h2>{{ persona.nombre }} {{ persona.apellido }}</h2>
      <p>DNI: {{ persona.dni }}</p>
      <p>Fecha de Nacimiento: {{ persona.fechaNacimiento | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
      <p>Correo Electrónico: {{ persona.email }}</p>
      <p>Teléfono: {{ persona.telefono }}</p>
      <p>Dirección: {{ persona.direccion }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En la consola me aparecio este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo resolvi.Mi problema era mi ruta :   registry.addResourceHandler("/imagenes/**").addResourceLocations("file:/C:/Users/Lautaro/Desktop/Proyectos/proyecto-clinica-odontologica/imagenes/"); le faltaba la ultima barra

Comment: prueba cambiando en el html `http://localhost:8080/imagenes/{{ persona.img }}` por `./imagenes/{{ persona.img }}`